# where to place the external java jar when deploy birt report?

Tags: birt

I use some java code to retrieve data from database, and export the java code as runnable jar, placed the jar in eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.viewer_3.7.1.v20110905\birt\scriptlib, then in the birt report I can use the jar to get the data. In eclipse all goes smoothly, I can see the correct data in preview.

but when I upload the myreport.rptdesign to the server, I don't know where to place the jar then the report can refer to it. In our team, they use grails to deploy birt report, all I need to do is upload the rptdesign file to a specified server directory, when there's no java jar to refer, that's enough. but when I need to refer to a java jar, I do not know how to deploy.

Please help and thanks a lot.

=========================================================
here is answer of my question. Just put the jar in directory lib of grails. It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to put the jar file in the server/lib directory? What kind of application server are you currently using?

Comment: Thank you so much. putting it in lib directory works.

Comment: It should be noted that the answer depends on the way you are integrating BIRT. Are you using the OSGI based BIRT or the plain-old-bunch-of-jars version? With the latter, your JARs have to be in the ClassPath, as usual.